# assing data and time (formats) for data.frame variable

Tags: r, dataframe, time, format, as.date

dears...

I need to get data in a data.frame considering date and time formats. For it I've created the data.frame structure like this:

```
df <- data.frame(action = character(),
                 date = as.Date(character(), format = "%Y%m%d"),
                 time = charcter()) #I didn't find a way to format time :(
```

I am reading the file using read_lines command and when I get the data from file I manage to format the date like this:

```
# Date position in line is 44-51
my_date <- as.Date(as.character(str_sub(line, 44, 51)), format = "%Y%m%d")
#Time position in line is 52-57
my_time <- paste(str_sub(l,52,53),":",str_sub(l,54,55),":",str_sub(l,56,57), sep="")
```

If I print my_date and my_time, the formats are perfect, but when I assign to data.frame it messes the format. I wish to use the date and time data in data.frame to compute information. It would be good if I have formats to compute the number of days, amount of hours, for example.

```
#dput of my_date
.structue(15431, class = "Date")
#dput of my_time
"18:59:39"
```

How can you see, I've put my_date in date format, but it messes when I assign in data.frame. About my_time I just put in character format to became visual, but I don't have an idea to format time in HH:MM:SS.

Tks for some help.

Hi, Ian
First of all, thanks for spending your time to help me.
The problem continues when I assign the value to data.frame. I think I am doing something wrong there. See...

When I collect the date and format:

```
[1] "2012-04-01" 
[1] "18:59:30"      
[1] "2012-04-01 18:59:00 -03"
structure(1333317540, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

The first line is the result for the print command over date variable formatted by

```
date <- as.Date(as. character(str_sub(l, 44,51), format = "%Y%m%d").
```

It's Ok!
The second line is the result for the print command over time variable formatted by

```
time <- paste(str_sub(l,52,53),":",str_sub(l,54,55),":",str_sub(l,56,57), sep="")
```

It's OK!

The 3dr line is the result for print command over date_time variable formatted by

```
date_time <- as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%OS")
```

It's perfect, according to your hint!

The 4th line is the result for dput(date_time), and the value passed to data.frame is 1333317540 3dr line instead.

I am declaring the blank data.frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ass_source = character(),
                           eot_ass_source = character(),
                           area_ass_source = character(),
                           #date = as.Date(character(), format = "%Y%m%d"),
                           #time = character(),
                           date_time = as.POSIXct(character(), format = "%Y-%m%d %H:M%OS"))
```

And I am inputting data like this (into a for loop):

```
df <- rbind(df, list(ass_source=ass_source, 
                     eot_ass_source=eot_ass_source, 
                     area_ass_source=area_ass_source,                                      
                     #date=as.Date(as.character(date), format= "%Y%m%d"), 
                     #time=time, 
                     date_time=date_time))
```

Comment: Hi Beto, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide `dput(my_date[1:10])` and `dput(my_time[1:10])`? You can [edit] your question and paste the output. Please surround the output with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: I've just shown the dput result.

TKS!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `my_date` is of class `Date` and you `my_time` is a character string. One convenient option is to use the `POSIXct` class which combines the date and time into one column. To do this, simply paste the two together and use `as.POSIXct`. It will be vectorized, you can do multiple at once.

```
my_date <- structure(15431, class = "Date")
my_time <- "18:59:39"
data.frame(time = as.POSIXct(paste(my_date,my_time)))
                 time
1 2012-04-01 18:59:39
```

Comment: My problem continues in assigning values to data.frame. It's the same of format as.Date, outside of data.frame it works, but when I assign value for the data.frame it messes format.